# Message pops up after I installed homebrew

Tags: 16.04

After I installed Homebrew this message pops up every time I start or reboot Ubuntu:

```
Error found when loading /home/lentakit/.profile
/home/lentkit/.profile line 21 brew: command not found
/home/lentkit/.profile line 22 brew: command not found
As a result the session will not be configured correctly 
Fix the problem as soon as feasible
```

this is the result from running `cat -n /home/lentakit/.profile`:

```
     1  # ~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.
 2  # This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
 3  # exists.
 4  # see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files for examples.
 5  # the files are located in the bash-doc package.
 6  
 7  # the default umask is set in /etc/profile; for setting the umask
 8  # for ssh logins, install and configure the libpam-umask package.
 9  #umask 022
10  
11  # if running bash
12  if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
13      # include .bashrc if it exists
14      if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
15      . "$HOME/.bashrc"
16      fi
17  fi
18  
19  # set PATH so it includes user's private bin directories
20  PATH="$HOME/bin:$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
21  export PATH="$(brew --prefix)/bin:$PATH"
22  export PATH="$(brew --prefix)/bin:$PATH"
23  export PATH="$(brew --prefix)/bin:$PATH"
```

What should i do ?

Comment: There is  an error in your `~/.profile` file online `21`, do `which brew` from the terminal to see if it even exists

Comment: It says that `brew` is not installed . If you certainly sure you installed `brew` check `echo $PATH` to see if `brew` command is on your path .

Comment: Please check my update

Answer (score 0):

It said from [here](http://linuxbrew.sh/) to add it to your `PATH` after running:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Linuxbrew/install/master/install)"
```

Did you add the following to your `~/.profile`?:

```
test -d ~/.linuxbrew && PATH="$HOME/.linuxbrew/bin:$PATH"
test -d /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew && PATH="/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin:$PATH"
test -r ~/.bash_profile && echo 'export PATH="$(brew --prefix)/bin:$PATH"' >>~/.bash_profile
echo 'export PATH="$(brew --prefix)/bin:$PATH"' >>~/.profile
```

Now if the above was done please check that these lines are in `~/.bash_profile`

```
export PATH="/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin:$PATH"
export MANPATH="/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/share/man:$MANPATH"
export INFOPATH="/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/share/info:$INFOPATH"
export PATH="$(brew --prefix)/bin:$PATH"
```

Then that this is in `~/.profile`

```
export PATH="$(brew --prefix)/bin:$PATH"
```

Now run the below line to add this line to your `/home/$USER/.bashrc`

```
echo 'export PATH="/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Source `~/.bashrc` with `source ~/.bashrc`. now close all terminals and relaunch the terminal and type: `which brew' and you should see:

```
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew
```

If it was done right.

Comment: yes , and i tried to install a package like this                                                      
    brew install hello

Comment: Please run `cat -n /home/lentakit/.profile` and lets see what causing the trouble

Comment: i have edited the question with the result of running `cat -n /home/lentakit/.profile`

Comment: Please edit that file and remove lines `22` and `23`, then  try again, please provide the link to the tutorial you followed

Comment: i followed this link [linuxbrew.sh](http://linuxbrew.sh/)

Comment: i edited the file and rebooted it now give the same error with line 21 only without line 22, should i remove line 21 also ?

Comment: Please I don't understand what you mean, please could you rephrase that?

Comment: Let me try installing on a VM

Comment: it gives me only one line of error  `/home/lentkit/.profile line 21 brew: command not found` instead of two   `/home/lentkit/.profile line 21 brew: command not found`  `/home/lentkit/.profile line 22 brew: command not found`

Comment: That means the install wasn't done well

Comment: What should i do ? remove it?

Comment: Please hold on let me try to install then I will let you know

Comment: @GeorgeGhaleb see my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Go to /home/lentkit (lenkit is your profile name) and open .profile file in a text editor(preferably like vscode so you can find the exact line).Go to the line at the mentioned in the error.in this case 21,and delete it.In fact delete every line that has anything to do with linuxbrew or home brew.This solution is only for removing homebrew completely from your system.

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal, type `gedit .profile`,
remove all that brew commands from where they start to end.
Save it and restart.
It should fix that error.

Warning: Brew will be totally removed.